# Bluetooth auto start up

Tags: 18.04

Hi Ubuntu Users / Experts,

can you help me how to disable bluetooth in start up for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?

Cant find anything that is working for this version from this forum.

Thank you

Comment: Without knowing what you tried, or if you tried them correctly, we are likely to send you back to try them again. A bit more information about that in your question might save you a lot of frustration.

Comment: hi, since I'm a new user in Ubuntu, this is only what I've tried.                        sudo systemctl disable bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

With tlp installed (if not sudo apt install tlp)

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
```

Find DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP, which can be set to

```
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth"
```

Now bluetooth will be disabled on each boot. After changing this configuration bluetooth will can be enabled and disabled through menu and panel item.

Also you need to disable Blueman to run at startup, cause this will enable again bluetooth.

Comment: I've had the problem of Bluetooth disabled upon startup. I've wondered about this for years but never had a pressing need to fix until buying a new bluetooth mouse. Unsure if this line is the default, or was added by me or an app years ago ... idk?  But my problem was essentially inverse of OP, "How to enable bluetooth on startup?" But I found the line in `/etc/default/tlp` and commented it out to disable. rebooted. worked like a charm and bluetooth is now enabled on startup.